# Do I need to install PHP to nginx? PHP files download instead of executing

Tags: php, nginx, indexing, download, execute

On my website "craff.ddns.net" (isn't online 24/7 yet) I didn't install php to nginx yet, becuse I'm not sure if I need to, and when I visit my website it just downloads the "index.php". I already asked a friend of mine who knows a bit more than me about webservers and he said I should set the index to "index.php", but I already have and it hasn't worked. Then he asked me if I installed php and I didn't. Will it automatically start to download "index.php" if I don't have php installed to nginx? And do I need to install php or is there anything else I need to install?

---

Btw I don't have anything installed on my nginx yet and I'm running nginx on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx needs a program to proccess the php file. You need to install the php-fpm package. 
Here is a sample location you need to enter in server block from the official doc.

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }

    # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;

    # include the fastcgi_param setting
    include fastcgi_params;

    # SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter is used for PHP FPM determining
    #  the script name. If it is not set in fastcgi_params file,
    # i.e. /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params or in the parent contexts,
    # please comment off following line:
    # fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```